# Passing form data to google sheets

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, google-sheets

I am trying to send form data from HTML to a google sheet. This is my jquery code:

```
    $.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
   var o = {};
   var a = this.serializeArray();
   $.each(a, function() {
       if (o[this.name]) {
           if (!o[this.name].push) {
               o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
           }
           o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
           o[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }
   });
   return o;
};
var v = $("#postStatus").serializeObject();
console.log(v);



function hideValidate(input) {
    var thisAlert = $(input).parent();
    $(thisAlert).removeClass('alert-validate');
    $(thisAlert).find('.btn-hide-validate').remove();
}
var $form = $('form#data-entry'),
    url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwuKy3XaIDoidAuP75V3Vs8QpDucbra5gjPCXEMe3HxIsJ/exec'

$('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $form.serializeObject()
  })
})
```

After I submit the form when I check my sheet, only the first column is getting filled in it, the rest of the columns are showing undefined.

I am not sure if the problem is in the above code or somewhere else. Just for reference, here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Siti - Agent Entry Form</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/iconic/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/noui/nouislider.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->

        <meta name="Siti Collection Entry Web Application" content="A data entry form for Siti Communications Group Agents">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container-contact100">
        <div class="wrap-contact100">
            <form action="agent.html" method="GET" id="data-entry" class="contact100-form validate-form" target="_blank">
                <span class="contact100-form-title">
                    Agent Entry
                </span>
                <form>
                <div class="wrap-input100 bg1 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter VC Number">
                    <span class="label-input100">VC Number</span>
                    <input class="input100" type="number" name="vc_no" id="vc_no" placeholder="Enter VC Number" required>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="container-contact100-form-btn">
                <button class="contact100-form-btn">
                    <span>
                        <a onclick='customerSearch()' id="search">Validate VC</a>
                        <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-7" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form>
            <div class="wrap-contact100">
                <span id="customer_details">
                        <div class="">
                                <ul class="label-input100">
                                    <p>Customer VC -</p>
                                    <li id="c_vc" class="input100"></li>
                                    <p>Customer Name -</p>
                                    <li id="c_name" class="input100"></li>
                                    <p>Customer Phone -</p>
                                    <li id="c_phone" class="input100"></li>
                                    <p>Due Date -</p>
                                    <li id="d_d" class="input100"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1" data-validate="Please Type Receipt Number">
            <span class="label-input100">Receipt Number *</span>
            <input class="input100" type="number" name="receipt" placeholder="Enter Receipt Number" required>
        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100" data-validate = "Enter Amount Paid by Customer">
            <span class="label-input100">Amount *</span>
            <input class="input100" type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Enter Amount Paid " required>
        </div>

        <div class="wrap-input100 input100-select bg1 validate-input" data-validate = "Select a Package">
            <span class="label-input100">Needed Services</span>
            <div>
                <select class="js-select2" name="package">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Package</option>
                    <option value=300>PKG 300</option>
                    <option value=250>PKG 250</option>
                    <option value=230>PKG 230</option>
                    <option value=200>PKG 200</option>
                </select>
                <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>

        </div>

        <div class="wrap-input100 bg0 rs1-alert-validate">
            <span class="label-input100">Remarks</span>
            <textarea class="input100" name="remarks" placeholder="Your message here..."></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100" data-validate = "Enter PIN to submit">
            <span class="label-input100">PIN *</span>
            <input class="input100" type="number" id="password-3" pattern="[0-9]*" name="pin" placeholder="Enter Your PIN " required>
        </div>

                    <div class="container-contact100-form-btn">
                    <button class="contact100-form-btn">
                        <span>
                            <input id="submit-form" type="button" onclick="return agentAuth()" href="agent.html" value = "Submit" />
                        <!-- <a id="next" onclick="return agentAuth()">Submit Entry</a> -->
                        <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-7" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </button>
                </div>
                <div>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>



<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/animsition/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(".js-select2").each(function(){
            $(this).select2({
                minimumResultsForSearch: 20,
                dropdownParent: $(this).next('.dropDownSelect2')
            });


            $(".js-select2").each(function(){
                $(this).on('select2:close', function (e){
                    if($(this).val() == "Please chooses") {
                        $('.js-show-service').slideUp();
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.js-show-service').slideUp();
                        $('.js-show-service').slideDown();
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/countdowntime/countdowntime.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->

<!--===============================================================================================-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/data.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

And my javascript:

```
function customerSearch(){

  var customer;
  var due_date;
  var phone;
  var vcid=document.getElementById('vc_no').value;
  // var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5", "dd/MM/yyyy")

for (var x in cust_DB){
  if (cust_DB[x]["VC No"]==vcid){
  customer = cust_DB[x]["Subscriber Name"];
  due_date = cust_DB[x]["Due Date"];
  phone = cust_DB[x]["Cel 1"];
  }
}
    if (customer==null){
        alert("Customer not found!");
        return false;
      }
    else {
      alert("Customer found!\nCustomer Name: " +customer)

      // location.reload(true);
      document.getElementById("c_vc").innerHTML = vcid;
      document.getElementById("c_name").innerHTML = customer;
      document.getElementById("c_phone").innerHTML = phone;
      document.getElementById("d_d").innerHTML = due_date;

      return [vcid, customer, phone, due_date];
    }
    }


function agentAuth() {

      var agent=document.getElementById('password-3').value;

      for (var x in agent_DB){
        if (agent_DB[x]["FIELD2"]==agent) {
          var agent_found=agent_DB[x]["FIELD1"];
        }
      }

      {if (customerSearch()==false) {
        alert("Enter customer details first!!")
        return false;
      }
      else if (agent_found==null){
          alert("Invalid PIN!");
          return false;
        }
      else {
          alert("Agent verification successful!");
          return true;
        }}
}
```

P.S: I am fairly new to programming and HTML.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please don't post your entire code here, only post that much where you feel lost.

Comment: I am sorry about that. I was not sure where I could have grown wrong hence the full code..